# Permissao para habilitar a geolocalização no celular nao funciona (React)

Tags: javascript, react, geolocalização

Eu preciso pegar a **geolocalização** do meu usuário no meu site, porém, no **celular**, a mensagem que pergunta 'deseja permitir sua geolocalização?' nao aparece no meu caso. No **pc**, funciona normalmente, apenas em mobile que nao. Já limpei o cache do navegador, cookies, troquei de navegador e mesmo assim nao funciona. Eu tentei com a lib **react-geolocated** e com o navigator, porém ambos os códigos nao funcionaram. Eis meus codigos:

***Usando a lib react-geolocated***

```
import React from "react";
import { useGeolocated } from "react-geolocated";
export default function Geolocation({ onAccept }) {

  
  let geolocationErrorHandled = false
  const {
    coords,
    isGeolocationAvailable,
    isGeolocationEnabled,
    positionError,
  } = useGeolocated({
    positionOptions: {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      maximumAge: 0,
      timeout: Infinity,
    },
    watchPosition: false, // Only get the user's position once
    suppressLocationOnMount: false,
    geolocationProvider: navigator.geolocation,
    isOptimisticGeolocationEnabled: true,
    watchLocationPermissionChange: false,

  

    onError: (error) => {
      if (!geolocationErrorHandled) {  
        console.error("Erro ao obter a geolocalização:", error);
        
        if (error.code === 1) {
          alert('Você não pode abrir a chamada se não habilitar a geolocalização');
        }
    
        geolocationErrorHandled = true;  
      }
    },
    onSuccess: (position) => {
      console.log("Geolocalização obtida:", position.coords);
      if (isGeolocationEnabled) {
        if(onAccept)
        {
          onAccept(); 
        }
      }
    },
  });
  return !isGeolocationAvailable ? (
    <div></div>
  ) : !isGeolocationEnabled ? (
    <div></div>
  ) : coords ? (
    <div>

    </div>
    // <table>
    //   <tbody>
    //     <tr>
    //       <td>latitude</td>
    //       <td>{coords.latitude}</td>
    //     </tr>
    //     <tr>
    //       <td>longitude</td>
    //       <td>{coords.longitude}</td>
    //     </tr>
    //     <tr>
    //       <td>altitude</td>
    //       <td>{coords.altitude}</td>
    //     </tr>
    //     <tr>
    //       <td>heading</td>
    //       <td>{coords.heading}</td>
    //     </tr>
    //     <tr>
    //       <td>speed</td>
    //       <td>{coords.speed}</td>
    //     </tr>
    //   </tbody>
    // </table>
  ) : (
    <div>Getting the location data&hellip; </div>
  );
}
```

***Usando o navigator***

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Geolocation({ onAccept }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.permissions
        .query({ name: "geolocation" })
        .then(function (result) {
          console.log(result);
          if (result.state === "granted") {
            //If granted then you can directly call your function here
            onAccept()
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, errors, options);
          } else if (result.state === "prompt") {
            //If prompt then the user will be asked to give permission
            onAccept()
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, errors, options);

          } else if (result.state === "denied") {
            //If denied then you have to show instructions to enable location
            alert("alo")
          }
        });
    } else {
      console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
  }, []);

  // Your render logic here
  return <div></div>;
}
```

Alguém tem ideia do por que isso está acontecendo? e se sim, pode me ajudar? agradeço, e feliz natal!